# Can you stop VS Code from moving the cursor when you tap to refocus a window?

Tags: visual-studio-code

If VS Code does not have focus and you click on the window to refocus the editor, the cursor moves to where you clicked in the window. For instance, I'm on line 5, but when I click to refocus the editor on line 10, my cursor jumps to line 10 and refocuses editor all in one click.

I'm not used to this behavior and I'm wondering if there's a way to disable it. I'm much more used to first click on window to refocus, then I click again to move the cursor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just disable the setting `window:click through inactive`.